# dynamic height of of scrollview subviews in autolayout ios

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, autolayout, constraints, subview

I am creating a UIScrollView from xib, in which 3 view are there 2 UIViews and in middle an UIImageView. when I am setting constraints Xcode asked to set Y position constrains. But the problem is Y position constraint is blocking Scrollview to scroll down and automatically adjusting the views  which looks ugly in landscape mode.

[image]

when I am delete that constraint it ask to fix height of subview. I searched a lot but I am new in autolayout so not understanding many of solutions. any help would be great.

Comment: Did you consider using a tableView?

Comment: did you give height constraint to UIImageview ?

Comment: @Adeel I want to use scrollview here.

Comment: @KKRocks I want dynamic height in Image view, It means top and bottom view will stick to the top and bottom screen and imageview will take all other remainig space. like layout_weight property in android

Comment: Can you briefly explain the scenario and the view hierarchy of your view controller and  the scrollview?

Comment: yes,, there are 3 views in my scrollview, lets consider top center and bottom. top and bottom are uiviews with height 50 each. center is imageview which I want to dynamic adjust acording to device and landscaoe modes.

Answer (score 2):

You have to set all the height constraints in the content view.
But you also want the height of the Content to be proportional to the screen size.

To do this assign the height constraint of the imageview [equal|proportional|a-computation-of] to the view containing the UISCrollView.

It seems weird to skip levels of herarchy when assigning constraints between two views whose are not direct ancestor/sibling of each other but within a scrollview (at least) it is perfectly acceptable.

You are basically telling the scrollview that it's content has a known size and at same time setting this content to adapt dinamically to the screen size (if the constraints of the root uiview are set correctly)

```
UIView1
|---UIScrollView
    |---UIView2
    |---UIImageView [heightConstr.constant=UIView1.height-UIView2.height-UIView3.height-margins]
    |---UIView3
```

This is the basic idea, to be done programmatically, then you can explore other solutions.

Unfortunately the constraint system in ios pretty much sucks when it's up to more complex equations involving more views for a single constraint.

Comment: +1 for explanation of  complexity in ios constraint but its not solving my problem so cant give you correct mark.

Comment: actually my viewcontroller contains the scrollview may be this would be a problem

Comment: Your view controller still has a root UIView no?

Answer (score 0):

`UIScrollView`can be tricky when adding constraints. You should always add a `subView` that will behave as the content view for your `UIScrollView` and all your subsequent views will go inside this content view.

```
UIView1
|---UIScrollView
    |---UIContentView
        |---UIView2
        |---UIImageView
```

Set your `UIScrollView`constraints as you would normally but set your content view to have leading, trailing, top and bottom to the `UIScrollView` but also add two more constraints which will be equal width and equal height to the `viewController.view` but will have a **low** priority (So that whichever direction your content will increase in, that constraint will break and automatically increase the content size of the scroll view by taking in the inferred height of the content view). Now go on and add constraints on all your `subview` as you normally would. Which i'm assuming would be:

1. Your topmost view will have top and leading and trailing to its `superView` and also a fixed height.
2. Your bottom view will have leading, trailing and bottom to its `superView` and also a fixed height.
3. Your `UIImageView`will have a leading, trailing and top to top most view and bottom to the bottom view.

**Edit:**
Here is the screenshot just in case (To show the view hierarchy with the content view's constraints in the inspector)

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't this give missing constraint to the UIView? The conentView and the imageView will mutally need each other height to compute their own.

Comment: Since the top and bottom views are attached and have a fixed height, whatever space remains will be adjusted with the `UIImageView`. Since the content view has a equal height equal to the whole view, it will have all the constraints the content view needs and break the equal height if required. If OP wants **atleast** a specific height or image to be displayed completely, he will have to make a height constraint of the `UIImageView` and update it programmatically with the height of the image.

Comment: To change a statement of mine in the previous comment, a constraint of `>=` also and that will ensure a minimum **height** and the rest will be figured out on the basis of the phone size.

Comment: If it works it is for sure a more clean solution than mine.